# Pandas: How to replace values to np.nan based on Condition for multiple columns

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, replace

Here is my dataframe.

```
I  A  B  C  D  E  F
1  9  4  0  T  F  F
2  0  5  1  S  X  J
3  1  8  0  G  G  J
```

Here is my expected output.
I want to replace if value in A ==0, repalce to np.nan in D.

```
I  A   B   C   D   E   F
1  9   4   0   T   F   nan
2  0   5   1   nan X   J
3  1   8   0   G   G   nan
```

I want to replace values on D/E/F columns by values of A/B/C columns.
For example, D column changes according to the A column. (A->D, B->E, C->F)

I tried this code but didn't change value.

```
list1 = ['A', 'B', 'C']
list2 = ['D', 'E', 'F']

for i in list2:
    for j in list1:
        df[i] = np.where(df[j] == 0, np.nan, df[i])
```

For below code, working well.
But there are lots of columns, so I want to using list and for sentence.

```
df['D'] = np.where(df.A == 0, np.nan, df.D)
```

Comment: `for x, y in zip(list1, list2): df[y] = df[y].where(df[x] != 0)` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First we create a dictionary from your two lists using `zip`

```
replace_dict = dict(zip(list1,list2))
```

then we loop over it to handle your assignments,

```
for k,v in replace_dict.items():
    df.loc[df[k] == 0, v] = np.nan

print(df)
   I  A  B  C    D  E    F
0  1  9  4  0    T  F  NaN
1  2  0  5  1  NaN  X    J
2  3  1  8  0    G  G  NaN
```

another method is to use `np.where` with your lists.

```
df[list2] = np.where(df[list1].eq(0), np.nan,df[list2])

print(df)

   I  A  B  C    D  E    F
0  1  9  4  0    T  F  NaN
1  2  0  5  1  NaN  X    J
2  3  1  8  0    G  G  NaN
```

Answer (score 3):

Let us do

```
df.loc[:,'D':].mask(df.loc[:,'A':'C'].eq(0).values)
     D  E    F
0    T  F  NaN
1  NaN  X    J
2    G  G  NaN
df.loc[:,'D':]= df.loc[:,'D':].mask(df.loc[:,'A':'C'].eq(0).values)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DataFrame.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) with [`DataFrame.rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) as:

```
df[list2] = df[list2].mask(df[list1].rename(columns=dict(zip(list1, list2))).eq(0))

print(df)
   I  A  B  C    D  E    F
0  1  9  4  0    T  F  NaN
1  2  0  5  1  NaN  X    J
2  3  1  8  0    G  G  NaN
```